# How to find the center of mass of a complex 2d shape

Tags: geometry, algorithms

So I'm hoping someone could help me get a solid algorithm for finding the center of mass of 2D shape without density, based of a set of vertices.

Please explain in simple terms that a non-mathematician could understand (I have no clue how the wikipedia equation works) and easily translate into C++ code for my program! =)

Note: if it makes the algorithm any faster, the complex shapes in my program are really just a group of convex polygons which I can access.

Comment: Like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2792443)? Or [this](http://books.google.com/books?id=CCqzMm_-WucC&pg=PA3) and [this](http://tog.acm.org/resources/GraphicsGems/gemsiv/centroid.c)?

Comment: I have code linked from my web page for this computation: [orourke](http://cs.smith.edu/~orourke/). It is also available in many other locations, of course.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. Divide your complex polygon into non-overlapping *triangles*.
2. The center of mass for each triangle is the simple average of the coordinates of its three corners. (Because this works for an equilateral triangle, and affine transformations preserve centroids and can take any triangle to any other triangle).
3. Average the centers-of-mass of all the triangles, weighting by the area of each triangle (which you can find as the 2D cross product of two of its sides).

Comment: While this is a valid approach, as @J.M. mentioned, there are much simpler approaches using the coordinates of the vertices directly. Of course, the proof of these formulas relies on Green's theorem or on triangulation, but finding a triangulation is a lot of work for just finding the centroid.

Comment: Ah, the OP does mention that the polygons are *convex*, in which case triangulating them is trivial.

Comment: At least one of the methods J. M. links to corresponds exactly to doing this, with a triangulation that consists of choosing a center arbitrarily at (0,0) and drawing lines from there to each vertex of the polygon. If the center is not inside the polygon (or if the polygon is sufficiently nonconvex), some of the triangles must then count negatively -- but the sign of the determinant/cross product handles this automatically.

Comment: Isn't area of the triangle *one half* of the cross product?

Comment: @Alexei, yes, but the scaling doesn't matter when you're weighting everything with doubled areas.